# Java List Duplicate

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I have this method that prints me the Profissional List,where through those conditions, i cant have duplicates for the name of the professional.
I wish to create another condition that doesnt let me have more than 3 Categories, being those ,Medicine,Nurse,Assistant.

```
public void RegistarProfissional(List<Profissional> rProfissional, String nomeP, String categoriaP) {
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < rProfissional.size(); i++) {
        if (rProfissional.get(i).nomeP.equals(nomeP)) {
            System.out.println("Existing Professional, error.");
            break;
        }

        if (i == rProfissional.size()) {
            rProfissional.add(new Profissional(nomeP, categoriaP));
            System.out.println("Professional registered");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see what the question is here.

Comment: @SephB I deciphered it, but he is more asking us to code an extra requirement, not fix anything that he currently posted.  He wants to add another condition that checks if the `List` currently has more than 3 categories, and the new "professional" is a 4th different category, don't add it to the list and error instead.

Comment: I want to create another condition in wich when i insert the categoriaP object in its list, it cant have more than the 3 values i wrote in there.

Comment: Ive been trying a lot of methods but none is working

Answer (score 1):

(adjusting your terms for English)

## Validation rules

Sounds like you are trying to validate the data in an existing list. You seem to have a pair of criteria for your validation rules:

- The list of `Professional` objects cannot have a duplicate name of the person.
- Each `Professional` object must carry a `profession` attribute with one of three values: Nurse, Physician, Assistant.

We will ignore the practical problem that two individuals can, in the real world, have the same name.

Our `Professional` class.

```
package work.basil.example;

public class Professional
{
    public String name, category;

    public Professional ( String name , String category )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

Dummy data.

```
List < Professional > pros = List.of(
        new Professional( "Alice" , "physician" ) ,
        new Professional( "Bob" , "nurse" ) ,
        new Professional( "Carol" , "assistant" ) ,
        new Professional( "David" , "physician" )
);
```

Test each of our two rules.

```
String targetName = "Bob";
String targetCategory = "driver";

// Test for category.
List < String > categories = List.of( "nurse" , "physician" , "assistant" );
if ( ! categories.contains( "targetCategory" ) )
{
    System.out.println( "Validation violation. The category: " + targetCategory + " not found in category list: " + categories );
    return;
}

// Test for duplicate name.
for ( Professional pro : pros )
{
    boolean foundDuplicateName = pro.name.equalsIgnoreCase( targetName );
    if ( foundDuplicateName )
    {
        System.out.println( "Validation violation. Duplicate name found: " + targetName );
        break;
    }
}
```

## Stream

We can use Java Streams and lambda syntax to do that check for duplicates.

Make a stream of your list.

```
Stream< Professional > prosStream = pros.stream() ;
```

For each `Professional` object produced by the stream, apply a predicate test  to see if the name in that object matches our target name. When the first match is found, an `Optional< Professional >` is returned. If we check inside that `Optional` object with `isPresent`, we get back `true`. If no match is found, an empty `Optional` will be returned, with `isPresent` returning `false`.

```
Stream < Professional > prosStream = pros.stream();
boolean foundDuplicateName =
        prosStream
                .filter( ( Professional pro ) -> pro.name.equalsIgnoreCase( targetName ) )
                .findFirst()
                .isPresent()
;
if ( foundDuplicateName )
{
    System.out.println( "Validation violation. Duplicate name found: " + targetName );
    return;
}
```

We can simplify that stream work. The method [`Stream::anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) has the same effect.

```
Stream < Professional > prosStream = pros.stream();
boolean foundDuplicateName =
        prosStream
                .anyMatch( ( Professional pro ) -> pro.name.equalsIgnoreCase( targetName ) )
;
if ( foundDuplicateName )
{
    System.out.println( "Validation violation. Duplicate name found: " + targetName );
    return;
}
```

We can reduce that to a one-liner.

```
if (  pros.stream().anyMatch( ( Professional pro ) -> pro.name.equalsIgnoreCase( targetName ) ) )
{
    System.out.println( "Validation violation. Duplicate name found: " + targetName );
    return;
}
```

## Enum

Rather than using mere strings for your `category` values, you should be using enums. Java has a simple yet powerful and flexible enum facility, much better than most languages. See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

```
package work.basil.example;

public enum Category
{
    NURSE , PHYSICIAN , ASSISTANT ;
}
```

Change our `Professional` class to use enum rather than mere String.

```
package work.basil.example;

public class Professional
{
    public String name;
    Category category;

    public Professional ( String name , Category category )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
    }
}
```

Instantiate like this:

```
Professional pro = new Professional( "Alice" , Category.PHYSICIAN ) ;
```

This would eliminate your check validation test for the category being one of the expected values. No `Professional` object would be instantiated with invalid value for `Category` because all the possible values are already defined, and the compiler checks for both type and value. Any attempts such as these will fail:

- `new Professional ( "Alice" , "driver" )` ➙ Compiler error due to type mismatch, the 2nd argument is `String` object where a `Category` enum object was expected.
- `new Professional ( "Alice" , Category.DRIVER )` ➙ Compiler error due to invalid value, as no such enum object `DRIVER` is defined on the enum class.

Answer (score 0):

I found it myself.
Just had to create this condition on the main file:

```
if(!categoriaP.equals("Medicina") && !categoriaP.equals("Enfermagem") && !categoriaP.equals("Auxiliar")) {
                        System.out.println("Categoria inexistente");
                        continue;
                    }
```

Thanks anyways